# How do we control which 3d View the render result is displayed in when multiple 3d views are visible?

Tags: rendering, customization

I'm rendering some simple 3d shapes to an isometric perspective (orthographic cameras etc) using the Blender internal.

The render is lightning fast so I dragged out another 3d view so Blender is divided into two 3d Views, one on the left one on the right. (Properties editor is on the far right as usual).

When I press <kbd>F12</kbd>, initially Blender displayed the render result on the right hand view.  This was great as I could make small changes to the camera (on the left) and immediately see changes in the full render just by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd> again.

However every so often when I press <kbd>F12</kbd>, Blender seems to randomly decide to put the render result in the left hand view and the right view now returns to the 3d View.

This a a real pain as I then have to re-open the tool and information panels and select the camera again etc.  It then also happens in reverse after a while (right now I'm rendering to the right window again).

I thought it may depend on which view I last selected an object in, but in my testing it seems to make no difference.

Does anyone know how I can lock the render result to a specific 3d view when there are multiple 3d views visible?

Comment: @Carlo, Thanks, yes this is absolutely a duplicate of that.  Happy for it to be closed etc.  Sorry, I did search first and also reviewed the suggestions when I was writing the question biut missed that somehow.

Comment: It took me a while for me also to remember where I saw a similar question...I think that your title is more accurate and easy to find, so it'll help who has the same doubts in the future.

Comment: We don't normally include an 'update' or 'solved' section in a question marked as 'duplicate' as the duplicate should provide enough information. I have taken the liberty of removing this section, though you could always roll back the edit if you feel it is really necessary.

Comment: No problems, I just thought it might be useful for someone else with identical question.  I'm new to this stackexchange so happy to fit in with the norms.